How to handle datatypes from various containers in templated classes deriving values from the container's elements?
I try to find a sane way to support custom ID datatypes for classes being based on various input datatypes. What does that mean?
Assume we have several possible data records D of type TD from which we can derive an ID of type TI. These data records live in all kinds of containers. Some examples:

std::vector<int>
std::set<double>
A C-array given by pointer/size, i.e. const float* p and size_t s

From all these containers, we can derive an ID for its elements. Furthermore, there is a class Dummy that requires to store these IDs internally. I want to prevent unnecessary copies by all means which is why I do not want the user of Dummy to first create the ID container himself and then copy it to the Dummy-constructor.
My first idea was to create the ID container on caller side and then move it into the Dummy constructor. I cannot say precisely why but this felt wrong to me (really, it is only a gut feeling).
Finally, I decided to go for a solution to pass an iterator to the caller's container and a little callback being able to compute the ID for each element (see code below).
This solution works, but it is not really nice because template argument deduction does not work here. This means, I always have to write down the target ID type twice - at the Dummy-constructor and at some point in the callback.
Overall: Is there a better solution than this? Can I improve my idea to get rid of the "duplicated datatype problem"?
#include <string>
#include <vector>   

template<typename IdType>
struct Dummy {
    template<typename InputIt, typename Converter>
    Dummy(InputIt first, InputIt last, Converter convert) {
        for (auto it = first; it != last; ++it) {
            _ids.push_back(convert(*it));
        }
    }
    std::vector<IdType> _ids;
};

int main() {
    std::vector<int> c1{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    auto d1 = Dummy<std::string>(c1.begin(), c1.end(), [](const auto& c) { return std::to_string(c); });

    std::pair<double, double> c2[2] = {{1.0, 2.0}, {3.0, 4.0}};
    auto d2 = Dummy<uint32_t>(c2, c2 + 2, [](const auto& c) { return static_cast<uint32_t>(c.first * c.second); });
}


You might use CTAD:
template<typename InputIt, typename Converter>
Dummy(InputIt it, InputIt, Converter convert) -> Dummy<decltype(convert(*it))>;

The call becomes
auto d2 = Dummy(c2, c2 + 2, [](const auto& c) { return static_cast<uint32_t>(c.first * c.second); });

Demo

wow, much more simple than mine

I actually did not know about this! The example was of course only a minimal abstraction of the actual problem (which is more complicated) but after some minor modifications it worked like a charm! Thanks all!

For the problem with CTAD, you can just write your custom deduction guide:
template <class InputIt, class Converter>
Dummy(InputIt, InputIt, Converter)
    -> Dummy<std::result_of_t<Converter(typename std::iterator_traits<InputIt>::value_type)>>;

Then, you can do simply:
auto d3 = Dummy(c1.begin(), c1.end(), [](const auto& c) { return std::to_string(c); });
auto d4 = Dummy(c2, c2 + 2, [](const auto& c) { return static_cast<uint32_t>(c.first * c.second); });

